# React Router Error when using URL Params in Loaders

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, frontend, mern

I'm using React-router in my React project. I have a movie page which looks like this

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom';

export async function loader({params}){
    const movieId = params.movieId
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/movies/'+movieId)
    const movie = res.data
    
    return {movie: movieId}
}

function SingleMoviePage(props) {

    const {movie} = useLoaderData()
    console.log(movie)

    return (
        <main>
            <h1>Single movie page</h1>
        </main>
    );
}

export default SingleMoviePage;
```

And my router looks like this

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout/>,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage/>,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <HomePage/>,
        loader: homeLoader
      },
      {
        path: 'movies',
        element: <MoviesPage/>,
      },
      {
        path: 'movies/:movieId',
        element: <SingleMoviePage/>
      }
    ]
  },

]);
```

I'm getting the following error when visiting `/movies/:movieId` route

```
Cannot destructure property 'movie' of ...
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `"/movies/:movieId"` route is missing the data loader function, so the `SingleMoviePage` has no returned loader response object to destructure from.

Add `loader` to the route.

```
...
import
  SingleMoviePage,
  { loader as singleMovieLoader }
from '../SingleMoviePage';
...

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <HomePage />,
        loader: homeLoader,
      },
      {
        path: 'movies',
        element: <MoviesPage />,
      },
      {
        path: 'movies/:movieId',
        element: <SingleMoviePage />,
        loader: singleMovieLoader, // <-- movie loader
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```